# EF Core 2.1 slow startup

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-core-2.0

After having some experience with EF6 (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441674/extremely-slow-ef-startup-15-minutes)), I wanted to try out EF Core, because I've read some articles and watched some videos saying that it outperforms EF6 by a very large margin.

So, I made sample program with class:

```
 public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }     

public class Employee : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I created a repository pattern with generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : IEntity
{
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
    void Update(T entity);
    void BeginTransaction();
    IDbContextTransaction Transaction { get; }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    private RosterContext _context;
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;

    public Repository(bool wrapTransaction = false)
    {
        _context = new MyContext();

        if (wrapTransaction)
        {
            _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        if (_transaction == null)
            _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        var toDelete = GetById(entity.Id);
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(toDelete);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }


    public IDbContextTransaction Transaction => _transaction;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _transaction?.Dispose();
        _context?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And this is context:

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public MyContext()
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is the simplest sample that there can be: one table, one entity with 2 properties stored in SQLite. The problem is, that first query takes almost 5 seconds with 10 rows in database. Next ones are instant.

I work on computer with SSD drive and i5 processor.

What is the problem? Is it SQLite? Is it `Database.Migrate();` (if I comment this line it does not change anything)? Or all performance improvements are just bad?

Comment: How long did the equivalent code take to run on EF 6?

Comment: I will check that tomorrow, but still, 5 seconds for 10 rows is way to long

Comment: When referring to database performance, tasks such as reading and writing data are all that really matter. When dealing with startup code and database migrations the results could vary quite a bit, but won't have any impact on end users. The results will also vary wildly for `Debug` vs `Release` build (the former of which users will never see).

Answer (score 4):

Actually the problem occurs only while debugging. The cause is that Entity Framework throws and catches thousands of exceptions, and they slow down the debugger. See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11765).

To solve it I enabled "Enable Just My Code" option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. That way Visual Studio does not trace the exceptions from Entity Framework.

Comment: this is possible, Release version was noticably faster. Since then I switched to EF6, because I needed some features that EF Core still lacks, so I cannot measure this.