# Dynamic database table creation in ASP.Net Core 2 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have problem on dynamic table or user will create table in the web application and will insert record after.How i can create a model on runtime without knowing number of columns inputted by user. Is EF can support this problem ?

Example

I have 1 textbox for tablename and then textbox2 for number columns
after inputting number of columns it will dynamically create textbox for column names and then user will save it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but I am afraid you cannot do that. But you can simulate it:

Classes for CodeFirst:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Column> Columns {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Row> Rows {get;set;}
}

public class Row
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public ICollection<ColumnValueBase> Values {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Column
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Column Column {get;set;}
}

public abstract class ColumnValue
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class IntColumn : Column
{
    public IntColumnValue IntValue {get;set;}
}

// other types of columns and values

public class TablesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Table> Tables {get;set;}
}
```

I used similar approach in my project and it works pretty well. Adding new types of columns is easy through migrations. Only problem may be performance - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441674/extremely-slow-ef-startup-15-minutes) is my question about it, but EF Core is supposed to be faster.