# Using JSON Schema while reading JSON to determine data type of property

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, jsonschema

I'm making a system that allows users to create their own data structures as descried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441674/extremely-slow-ef-startup-15-minutes), but still sometimes there are scenarios when users need more complex data. For that reason I want to add XML/JSON type of field, for which users could edit the schema.

By that I mean, user could define that the object needs a name and at least one step that has a date, path to pdf and name of some resource used during the process. I would like to save that definition as schema.

First of all, I'm trying to decide which technology to use. I don't care about XML database side optimizations, since I need to load the whole thing at the start.

I know that XML is more mature and I'm leaning towards it.

On the other hand, JSON is simpler and cleaner, but looses more information, like data types. I need to know the type for UI - I will store text, but if it is a path, I need to display it as a button.

I work in C#, so there are many libraries to handle XML, and one for JSON with paid add-on for schemas.

Have you tried something like that? With which technology?

What strategy should I use for schema creation?

Comment: _"one for JSON with paid add-on for schemas"_ - I guess you are talking about NewtonSoft.JSON Schema addon. The pricing seems relatively moderate if you really need it to fortify against unknown JSON. It also seems to me much more convenient than using XML, especially if users shall be able to define their own schemas. BUT: that's just _my opinion_ - I am afraid this question _could_ be closed as such: basically opinion based.

Comment: JSON Schema has many implmentations, not just one which is paid =]

Comment: @Fildor yes, I fully agree that price is adequate and I'm prepared to pay it. And also I fully agree that it is opinion based, but I wanted to get some opinions with argumetns from both sides preferably.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek why don't you check free MIT implementation enlisted here: [link](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators).
Moreover, why don't you provide your users hints how to structure JSON schema? I don't know what would do the trick for you, but by getting properly structured "definitions" you could have something that *pretends* to be a data type your UI expects, like: 

`"definitions" : {
  "path" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "pattern" : "your regex for paths here",
  }
}`

and cast prop valid for e.g. "#/definitions/path" to data type your C# UI needs.