# Loading instance of entity takes more than 1 second

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I ran into one interesting thing in EF. If we get child entity using base entity, loading entities takes more time. My model looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseDocument
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ComplexDocument : BaseDocument
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SimpleDocument : BaseDocument
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OfficeDocument : ComplexDocument
{
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ClassDocument : SimpleDocument
{
    public string HeadName { get; set; }
}

public class WordDocument : OfficeDocument
{
    public int PagesCount { get; set; }
}

public class ExcelDocument : OfficeDocument
{
    public int SheetsCount { get; set; }
}

public class TextDocument : ClassDocument
{
    public int LinesCount { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the **TPT** approach. Here is the inheritance tree
[image: inheritance tree]
Here is my context class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EFSIX;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
    public DbSet<BaseDocument> BaseDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ComplexDocument> ComplexDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SimpleDocument> SimpleDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeDocument> OfficeDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassDocument> ClassDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExcelDocument> ExcelDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WordDocument> WordDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TextDocument> TextDocuments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<BaseDocument>().ToTable("BaseDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<ComplexDocument>().ToTable("ComplexDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<SimpleDocument>().ToTable("SimpleDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeDocument>().ToTable("OfficeDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExcelDocument>().ToTable("ExcelDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<WordDocument>().ToTable("WordDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<ClassDocument>().ToTable("ClassDocuments");
       modelBuilder.Entity<TextDocument>().ToTable("TextDocuments");
    }
    public IQueryable<T> GetEntities<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Set<T>();
    }
}
```

I'm creating some data:

```
static void CreateTestData()
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ExcelDocument excel = new ExcelDocument()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AuthorName = $"ExcelAuthor{i}",
                    Name = $"Excel{i}",
                    OfficeName = $"ExcelOffice{i}",
                    SheetsCount = (i + 1) * 10
                };
                context.ExcelDocuments.Add(excel);

                WordDocument word = new WordDocument()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    AuthorName = $"WordAuthor{i}",
                    Name = $"Word{i}",
                    OfficeName = $"WordOffice{i}",
                    PagesCount = (i + 2) * 10
                };
                context.WordDocuments.Add(word);

                TextDocument text = new TextDocument()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Name = $"Text{i}",
                    LinesCount = (i + 3) * 10,
                    HeadName = $"Head{i}",
                    Level = i + 5
                };
                context.TextDocuments.Add(text);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I made some two methods for getting `WordDocument` from db. One of them using `BaseDocument` and another one using `WordDocument`. Both returns 20 instances of `WordDocument`:

```
 static long ReadBaseDoc()
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            var words= context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Word"));
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var instacnes = excel.ToList();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
    static long ReadWordDoc()
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            var words = context.GetEntities<WordDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Word"));
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var instacnes = words.ToList();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

I tested moth method separately, several times, in average method `ReadWordDoc` takes 25ms and method `ReadBaseDoc` takes 52ms (instances are the same ). 
It's not too big problem now, but when we have complex inheritance it takes more than 1 second. I created 10 classes and inherited from `BaseDocument`. After that I executed `ReadBaseDoc` and `ReadWordDoc` methods. `ReadWordDoc` took 25ms and `ReadBaseDoc` took 1023ms. Instances are the same, why `ReadBaseDoc` takes more time? What is the better way to avoid this kind of problems in EF?

Comment: afaik, the main performance issues in EF have to do with connection establishment, model creation, query computation and materializing, where the first two will happen on the first call of a specific context class, the third with each first (sub-)query with specific conditions, and the fourth every time. So there will be an overhead, but it shouldnt be very significant once you've did the first queries.Regarding the questions there's a lot more to mention, but it all boils down to these four points.

Comment: Could you add what exactly `GetEntities` and also include the model. How many records are trying to fetch

Comment: @Eldho, I added some details

Comment: Put your test in a loop and repeat it 1000 times. This should show if the latency is overhead from first time spin-up.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, I tested several times, difference is not big

Comment: I think its the first time spin up as @ChrisPickford mentioned. In your last sample try to switch ExcelDocument and Document and i think the second time is always the fast one.

Comment: what type of inheritance is used TPT or TPH. please include those information and details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @VSDekar, They are in several tests

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you would share much more code / all your tests etc.

Comment: @VSDekar, I added all codes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441674/extremely-slow-ef-startup-15-minutes). There are ways to make EF faster, but in those complex scenarios ORM just creates more problems than it solves.

One way in your case would be to try to change the inheritance to TablePerType, MAYBE it will be a little bit faster.

Other way would be to locate the slow request and use Dapper for them - it will be much faster.

Last way would be to create a Repository with live cache that loads the full database into memory and keeps it up to date - this should be a singleton in an app. If you have more than one app using the same database, you need to hookup data change triggers.

In general, I would say for slow (and relatively simple) queries like yours, use Dapper + AutoMapper. Keep EF so that your database stays synchronized with your classes, but do not rely on it for queries.

If you really want to stick to ORM, I think you need to switch nHibernate. Haven't try it myself, but form what I read, it is superior in almost every possible way, that includes performance and startup time.