# How to concat IQueryable<T> and List<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concatenation, iqueryable

I have `BaseDocument`, `TextDocument`, `ExcelDocument` and `WordDocument` classes. They inherited from `BaseDocument`. I have collections for each classes. Lets say `BaseDocuments` collection gets value from some collection of child entities in some places. Collections type are different, some of them List, another one is `IQueryable`    and another specific type. `BaseDocuments` collection is `IQueryable` type and gets value from some child entities collection.

It looks like this:

```
 using (Context context = new Context())
 {
    var words = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Word")).ToList(); // type of collection is list

    var excels = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Excel"));

    var texts = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Text"));

    var wordsAsQuery = words.AsQueryable();

    baseDocuments = wordsAsQuery.Concat(excels).Concat(texts);
 }
```

As you can see I'm using `Concat` method. But when I do

```
var instances = baseDocuments.ToList();
```

it throws exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'

I did some researching and every time after fixing code, I'm getting another exceptions such as

> LINQ error DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible
> collection ResultTypes.

I can do ToList all child collections, but it doesn't make sense and it will be performance problem.

How can I concat different types of collections to `IQueryable` collection? Is it possible?

For more information about model, you can see my last question :  [Loading instance of entity takes more than 1 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946573/loading-instance-of-entity-takes-more-than-1-second)

Comment: Why not just call `context.BaseDocuments.Where( condition || condition || condition).ToList()` ?

Comment: `AsQueryable` is **very rarely** useful. Remove it.

Comment: @TheGeneral, because condition1, condition2 ... are used in different places, in child collections and we don't know about it. We know only there childs collections and base collection get value from them

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can repro the issue. That [mcve] must have **everything needed** in it (including `GetEntities`).

Comment: @mjwills, No, I'm saying code above works and when we do baseDocuments.ToList(); it will throw exception

Comment: Does it work if you use `var words = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Word"));` instead (and remove the `AsQueryable`)?

Comment: You are missing critical information here, the errors don't match the code, also DbContext has no GetEntities as far as i knew

Comment: @TheGeneral, Look at link below of question. I showed Context class and there is GetEntities method

Comment: @DIlshod All of the code must be **in this question**. Not elsewhere.

Comment: @KanisXXX Your explanation is really misleading. You could easily concat a `List`, which is a class, with any `IEnumerable`, which is an interface, when using LINQ to Objects. It has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you first `ToList`ing the Word documents and then doing `AsQueryable` on them? You're causing LINQ to forget everything about the database structure and handle the `word` collection in-memory. When you then tell it to `Concat` with actual queries you get the error you specified. Why not just:

```
using (Context context = new Context())
{
   var words = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Word"));

   var excels = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Excel"));

   var texts = context.GetEntities<BaseDocument>().Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("Text"));

   baseDocuments = words.Concat(excels).Concat(texts);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it because type of words collection is List. Also I put comment on it

Comment: @DIlshod The type of the `words` collection is `List`, because you make it so willingly by calling `ToList`. There's no point in doing that and your code sample can be easily fixed, as I have shown. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Just think, that words is List collection not IQuerable